# Server not visible from the internet

Tags: apache-http-server, lan, webserver

I am trying setting up a small HTTP Server visible from the internet using DynamicDNS.

As DynDNS Service I'm using DuckDNS.org. I set up the DynamicDNS service on my router and the IPs (on my router and on DuckDns) are up to date so I assume it's working.

I then set up the port forwarding from the router to my computer (Running Linux and Apache) and everything seems ok.

The website works using the DynDNS domain only when I'm using my local connection. I can see my web page and everything works fine. When i try to access it using a different connection (Like 4G on my phone) the domain seems to not respond and even if I try to ping the public ip of the router (or the dyndns domain) the request times out.

I can't understand what is the problem: have I misunderstood the principle behind the connection? Or is it some sort of firewall thing?

Any help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try manually the Duck DNS update URL that you programmed on the router to see its full answer. Add `&verbose=true` to the request for more information.

Comment: Make certain you have e.g. `Listen 80` (i.e. not `Listen 1.2.3.4:80`) in your `httpd.conf`. Likewise, make certain the virtual host for your dynamic DNS website starts with `<VirtualHost *:80>` not e.g `<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a **route-able** public ip address on your router, probably your router is behind NAT. you can't use ddns service in this situation. you must buy or rent a public address from your service provider if is possible.

Comment: I think this could be the problem. I did some research and some other people with my ISP have the same problem too. Is there any way to resolve this thing without buying a static IP? Like for example, if I call my isp are they able to make me bypass the NAT?

Comment: Most stable way is to buy a public ip address from your service provider, but yes there are some other ways for example using same vpn tunnel service with different private ipaddresses on your client and your server then you can access your private vpn address on your server from your client but you must try different vpn services to find if it's possible or not, because on some vpn services it's not possible. for bypassing NAT I'm not sure if it's possible or not.

Comment: If my answer was the answer for your question you can accept it as correct one.

Answer (score 0):

you could try pinging the DDNS address using a terminal or command prompt when you ping it, it should say pinging (your public IP) (Atleast on windows). Also,make sure to forward a port on your router that leads to the Ipv4 address of the computer running the https server?

Comment: Pinging the ddns address on cmd gives me the right IP address (the router one) so at least the ddns service an its updating are working. Anyway, even if the address resolves, the ping request times out. I'm not sure whether I have or not forwarded a port for https (the 443 one I think?): I'll check but, as I was trying to connect using http I don't think that much would change. Thanks anyway :D